# slack files.upload - how to send a file as payload from javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload, slack

I'm trying to post an image to slack from a javascript/jQuery based application. The image is generated on the fly and stored in a static location and I don't want the user to upload the file. Is there a way to get the file reference/handle in javascript and use it as payload for the ajax post query to the files.upload method in slack?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a reference for uploading a file to Slack. But you can indeed upload files to Slack with Javascript using the API method `file.upload`.

Instead of a reference send the content of your file to Slack. You then get a Slack file reference back which you can use in other Slack methods.

The required parameters for `file.upload` are `token` and either `file` or `content`.

See the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) on Slack for further information.